# Removing Azure AD authentication from ASP.Net MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, authentication

A few months ago I created a small web application in ASP.NET MVC, I got it to work with Azure AD Authentication, now I need to strip the application of the Azure part and have it run without the user needing to login, I have commented or removed all the stuff that is added according to this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/vs-active-directory-dotnet-what-happened

But the application stills fails with

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page

when loading my `Home/Index.cshtml` page

Thanks!

Comment: Does it still fail when you drop ".cshtml"? Just use "Home/Index". You'll need to show your startup code and the controller code to get better answers.

Comment: Yea somewhat difficult without examples, sorry mate.

Comment: @Jasen Yes, it does it without ".chstml"